# Finding Xpath From Div Container

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, bots, webautomation

I am making a python bot which will login on the Linkedin.After logging I am going to make it to connect to all people who meet some specific criteria.I get the list of all those people but how can i click on the connect button with the div container or can find xpath from its container

Comment: Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code will click on the connect button when you are on a page, and the connect button is shown to the right of the profile picture.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="ember1355"]/button').click()
```